Calculate Sub Total as Row
Suppose I have a data model joined by category.id and transaction.category_id on these two tables:
category:



id
code




1
a


2
b


3
c



transaction:



category_id
amount




1
100


1
200


1
300


2
50


2
100


2
200



In a table visualization in PowerBI, if I just bring category and amount as is, I get the following as expected. a and b have transactions and the sum of each is displayed accordingly:

But is there a way to show category c? maybe as a total of category a and b, and still have the Total line total correctly?
For example, here a and b sum by category but c sums a collective total of a and b:

Is this possible with DAX as a measure field?

This would be the most straightforward approach that returns the expected result.
Amount with Subtotals = 
SUMX (
    Categories,
    IF (
        Categories[Category Code] = "c",
        CALCULATE (
            SUM ( Transactions[Amount] ),
            REMOVEFILTERS ( Categories ),
            TREATAS ( { "a", "b" }, Categories[Category Code] )
        ),
        CALCULATE ( SUM ( Transactions[Amount] ) )
    )
)



you can try to create measures
MEASURE =
IF (
    SELECTEDVALUE ( category[code] ) = "c",
    CALCULATE ( SUM ( 'transaction'[amount] ), ALL ( 'transaction' ) ),
    SUM ( 'transaction'[amount] )
)

Measure 2 = sumx(VALUES(category[code]),[Measure])


